# notes/materials for short couple of lectures in statistics (causal inference) with minimal math

Tags: references, causality, intuition, teaching

I'm doing research as part of a project being implemented by a NGO that does randomized controlled trials of international development projects, and I spend a lot of time here in Kenya.  The management staff is in charge of managing big teams of enumerators, who collect data on behalf of people like me (though usually more senior).

These people work for quantitative researchers, but they have little training in or understanding of what is actually being done with the data.  As a consequence, researchers and staff often communicate poorly, because researchers often forget what other people know and don't know.

I've offered to teach a very short stats course.  My goal is that by the end of it, they will know how to interpret basic regression output, and know how to think about whether the estimates that they see have causal interpretation or not.  This is super-basic econometrics.  Most of these people have been to university, but quantitative training seems limited.

I've taught intro econometrics to undergrads, but we did things more slowly than I have time for, and more rigorously than would be useful for these people.  So my question:

**Can anyone recommend good materials that I can use to guide a short series of lectures?**